# Solving a SymPy Equation for Numeric Solution

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I am writing some vector equations that solve a planar vector-loop closure equation (the four vectors form a loop in a mechanism).:

> R1=np.array([L1*smp.cos(theta1),L1*smp.sin(theta1)])
> R2=np.array([L2*smp.cos(theta2),L2*smp.sin(theta2)])
> R3=np.array([L3*smp.cos(theta3),L3*smp.sin(theta3)])
> R4=np.array([L4*smp.cos(theta4),L4*smp.sin(theta4)])
>
> i_comps=Eq(R1[0]+R4[0]-R2[0]-R3[0],0)
>
> j_comps=Eq(R1[1]+R4[1]-R2[1]-R3[1],0)
>
> pos_sol=smp.solve([i_comps,j_comps],[theta3,theta4],dict=True)

The position analysis is straightforward. I then used Sympy to differentiate the above equations with respect to time, using the chain rule. This would enable me to solve for the angular velocities and accelerations of each link. This worked out, but now I have coupled symbolic equations that have derivative terms.
An example of one of these equations is shown here:

> `−1()sin(1())1()+cos(1())1()`

What I want to do is assign known values in the symbolic equation, and solve for `$\frac{d\theta}{dt}$`. For example, I want to plug in numeric values for $\theta1, L1, and \frac{d\L1}{dt}$ to solve for the angular velocity term. I considered using Lambdify but it is not clear how I will specify the derivative terms, such as $\frac{dL1}{dT}=0$.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy will handle the "plugging in" if you just give it a list of equations with the known information, e.g. if you want to solve `a + b*x` with `a=2` and the sum of `a` and `b` equal to the negative value of `x`:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import a, b
>>> solve([a + b*x, Eq(a, 2), Eq(a + b, -x)])
[{a: 2, b: -1 + sqrt(3), x: -sqrt(3) - 1}, {a: 2, b: -sqrt(3) - 1, x: -1 + sqrt(3)}]
```

In your case you could just use `subs` to substitute in the known values and then solve for the unknown value, too.

```py
>>> eq = a + b*x
>>> solve(eq.subs({a:1, b:2}))
[-1/2]
```

Substituting symbols or derivatives is the same:

```py
>>> f=Function('f')
>>> f(x)+f(x).diff(x)
f(x) + Derivative(f(x), x)
>>> _.subs(f(x).diff(x),2).subs(x,3)
f(3) + 2
```